# Why is NAudio creating a WAV file that's twice the size it should be?

Tags: naudio

I'm using this fairly standard code sample to mix multiple WAV files into one output file (Dispose calls omitted for clarity):

```cs
public static void MixAudioFiles(IEnumerable<FileObject> input, FileObject output)
{
    var mixer = new WaveMixerStream32 { AutoStop = true };

    foreach (var file in input)
    {
        var reader = new WaveFileReader(file.FullName);

        mixer.AddInputStream(new WaveChannel32(reader));
    }

    WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(output.FullName, new Wave32To16Stream(mixer));
}
```

But the output file is always twice the size of the input file, despite the use of `Wave32To16Stream`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: possibly you are going from mono to stereo?

Comment: Entirely possible, but I don't see how. Does one of the `WaveXXX` objects in this chain have that effect by default?

Comment: @MarkHeath: It seems that the problem is that the mixed file has 2 channels, but the input files only have 1. I think this is because `WaveMixerStream32` uses a `WaveFormat` with 2 channels, but I can't see any way to create a mixer that uses only 1 channel.

Comment: Look at the `MixingSampleProvider` - `WaveMixerStream32` and `WaveChannel32` are very old classes that are best not used any more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7532/mark-heath), that pointed me in the right direction. For anyone else with this issue, here's the working code:

```
    public static void MixAudioFiles(IEnumerable<string> input, string output)
    {
        var wf = new WaveFormat(16000, 1);

        var mixer = new NAudio.Wave.SampleProviders.MixingSampleProvider(WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(wf.SampleRate, wf.Channels));

        foreach (var file in input)
        {
            var reader = new WaveFileReader(file);

            mixer.AddMixerInput(reader);
        }

        //write the mix file
        WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile16(output, mixer);
}
```

Note that I've omitted the `Dispose` calls. Make sure to add these to prevent resource leaks.